# PostgreSQL filter entries by date but include missed ones with null date

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-10

Let's say that i have a simple table such as:

```
CREATE TABLE public.test
(
    id integer NOT NULL,
    d date NOT NULL
)
```

with data:

```
insert into test values(1, '2018-09-05'::date);
insert into test values(2, '2018-08-05'::date);
insert into test values(2, '2018-07-05'::date);
```

How could i, in a simplest way possible, get both entries with date being **null** for the record that doesn't meet date filter?
E.G.

```
select id, d from
test where d > '2018-09-01'
union
select id, d from test;
```

Gives:

```
 2  "2018-07-05"
 2  "2018-08-05"
 1  "2018-09-05"
```

and i would like:

```
2   "null"
1   "2018-09-05"
```

Can't use distinct across union, not that it would help.
I should maybe join this table to itself and do something but i am not sure what.

Comment: Not sure if i understand your expected results here.. Why is there is a NULL with a id of 2 there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly you could move the condition to your select:

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCT
    id, 
    (case when d > '2018-09-01' then d end) as d 
FROM 
    test
```

Comment: Look ok but i would use `(case when d > '2018-09-01'::date then d else null end) as d` instead.. So PostgreSQL compares true dates types and not a date type vs a string type

Comment: This cast should be automatic. But I agree.

Answer (score 1):

My solution:

```
select distinct 
  t.id,
  (select max(t_max.d) from test t_max where t_max.id = t.id and t_max.d > '2018-09-01')
from test t;
```

you can test it [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/a1934/5/0).